combine records based on date in between fields
--This is a SQL code
I am expecting a compression or combination of records to be considered as continuously prescribed medication. The goal is to figure out how long a patient was on the same drug/order type.  considering continuous orders in the sense, that for the same  generic_name and route type with the candence = nulll it retains the same value but if for the same type of generic_name and route and cadence is not null in one of the records that means the drug has been extended for the Cadence_value-- number of days from the end date of the prior order.
for the example of patid=135 , Cadence_value is not null and equals to 30 the e_date (extended date) will be 08/04/2017=(2017-07-05 plus 30 days).All records with the same generic and type ='R' will collapse/fold up into a single record as long as they have a s_date <= extended_date (08/04/2017) .If the s_date extends beyound the highest cadence_value even with the same generi_name and type, that will fall under be a different group.
Sample data



patid
Generic_Name
Route
Route_value
s_date
e_date
cadance_value




135
Haloperidol Decanoate
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
14


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
O
IM
2017-03-29
2017-03-29
null


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-02-16
2017-07-05
null


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-04-07
2017-07-05
30


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-07-20
2017-07-21
null


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-07-27
2018-07-27
null


135
risperiDONE Consta
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
null



Expected result



patid
Generic_Name
Route
Route_value
s_date
e_date
cadance_value




135
Haloperidol Decanoate
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
14


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
O
IM
2017-03-29
2017-03-29
null


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-02-16
2018-07-27
30


135
risperiDONE Consta
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
null



Code to generate the data
            drop table #prescribed_data
            drop table #prescribed_data_Result

            CREATE TABLE #prescribed_data (
            [patid] [varchar](20) NULL
            ,[Generic_Name] [varchar](256) NULL
            ,[Route] [varchar](50) NULL
            ,[Route_value] [varchar](50) NULL
            ,[s_date] DATE
            ,[e_date] DATE
            ,[cadance_value]  int--if not null
            ,[ext_date] DATE--end date plus candance value


            )

            INSERT INTO #prescribed_data
            VALUES
            ('135','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','IM','2017-04-05','2017-07-05',14,'2017-07-19')
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','IM','2017-03-29','2017-03-29',null,'')
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','IM','2017-02-16','2017-07-05',null,'')
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','IM','2017-04-07','2017-07-05',30,'2017-08-04')---as long as start date is within the extended date 
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','IM','2017-07-20','2017-07-21',null,'')
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','IM','2017-07-27','2018-07-27',null,'')
            ,('135','risperiDONE Consta','R','IM','2017-04-05','2017-07-05',null,'')

            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2017-01-12','2017-01-31' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2017-02-01','2017-04-13',NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2017-04-13','2018-04-13' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2018-04-13','2018-07-18',NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2018-07-18','2019-07-18' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2020-06-11','2020-06-11' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2020-06-23','2020-08-18' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2020-08-18','2021-08-18' ,NULL,'')
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2021-08-18', '2022-08-18',NULL,'')

            ,('123','Haloperidol Decanoate','IM','R','2016-07-22','2016-07-26',14,'2016-08-09')
            ,('123','Paliperidone Palmitate','IM','o','2016-07-22','2016-07-23',NULL,   NULL)
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta',   'IM','o','2016-02-03','2016-02-04', NULL,NULL)
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta',   'IM','R','2016-02-17','2016-04-04', 14,'2016-04-18')
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta',   'IM','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-10',21,'2016-08-31') 


            ,('128','Haloperidol Decanoate','IM','R','2016-07-21','2016-07-26',14,'2016-08-09')
            ,('128','Paliperidone Palmitate','IM','o','2016-07-23','2016-07-24',NULL,NULL)
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-01-27','2016-04-01',14,'2016-04-15')
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-06-07','2016-06-07',14  ,'2016-06-21')
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-06-14','2016-07-18',14  ,'2016-08-01')
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-08-03','2016-08-09',NULL,NULL)



            ------desired result

            CREATE TABLE #prescribed_data_Result (
            [patid] [varchar](20) NULL
            ,[Generic_Name] [varchar](256) NULL
            ,[Route] [varchar](50) NULL
            ,[Route_value] [varchar](50) NULL
            ,[s_date] DATE
            ,[e_date] DATE
            ,[cadance_value]  int

            )

            INSERT INTO #prescribed_data_Result
            VALUES
            ('135','Haloperidol Decanoate','R','IM','2017-04-05','2017-07-05',14)
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','O','IM','2017-03-29','2017-03-29',null)
            ,('135','Paliperidone Palmitate','R','IM','2017-02-16','2018-07-27',30)
            ,('135','risperiDONE Consta','R','IM','2017-04-05','2017-07-05',null)

            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2017-01-12','2019-07-18' ,NULL)
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2020-06-11','2020-06-11' ,NULL)
            ,('106','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2020-06-23','2020-08-18' ,NULL)

            
            ,('123','Haloperidol Decanoate INTRAMUSCULAR','IM','R','2016-07-22','2016-07-26',14)
            ,('123','Paliperidone Palmitate INTRAMUSCULAR','IM','o','2016-07-22','2016-07-23',NULL)
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta INTRAMUSCULAR', 'IM','o','2016-02-03','2016-02-04', NULL)
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta INTRAMUSCULAR', 'IM','R','2016-02-17','2016-04-04', 14)
            ,('123','risperiDONE Consta INTRAMUSCULAR', 'IM','R','2016-07-27','2016-08-10',21)  

            ,('128','Haloperidol Decanoate','IM','R','2016-07-21','2016-07-26',14)
            ,('128','Paliperidone Palmitate','IM','o','2016-07-23','2016-07-24',NULL)
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-01-27','2016-04-01',14)
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-06-07','2016-07-18',14)
            ,('128','risperiDONE Consta','IM','R','2016-08-03','2016-08-09',NULL)
        


            select * from #prescribed_data
            --order by patid,Route,Generic_Name,Route,S_Date

            select * from #prescribed_data_Result
            --order by patid,Route,Generic_Name,Route,S_Date


The dates 08/04/2017 and 2017-07-20 do not appear in your expected results. Please explain how you get an e_date of 2018-07-27 for the row with Cadance_value=30

Please include multiple patid values in your sample date to make it clear how the data should be grouped when multiple patients have the same Generic_Name.

Note that tables have columns, not fields. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used. (I'm not sure Sybase t-sql and MS SQL Server t-sql are fully compatible.)

Doesn't the same IM route value for all rows make the problem too simple?

@BartMcEndree.I have added more sample data.

@jarlh. Its MS SQL Server

You seem to want something like this. It's a gaps and islands problem with the dates. First eliminate the ranges that are fully subsumed by larger ranges. After that they can be consistently ordered and checked for overlap:
with tagged as (
    select *,
        dateadd(day, coalesce(cadance_value, 0), e_date) as extended_date,
        dense_rank() over (order by patid, Generic_Name, Route, Route_value) as dr,
        row_number() over (order by patid, Generic_Name, Route, Route_value,
                           s_date, dateadd(day, coalesce(cadance_value, 0), e_date)) as rn
    from T
), nonsubsumed_ranges as (
    select * from tagged t where not exists (
        select 1 from tagged t2 where t2.dr = t.dr and
        (
            (t2.rn <  t.rn and  t2.s_date  = t.s_date and t2.extended_date =  t.extended_date)
         or (t2.rn <> t.rn and (t2.s_date <= t.s_date and t2.extended_date >  t.extended_date
                            or  t2.s_date <  t.s_date and t2.extended_date >= t.extended_date))
        )
    )
), breaks as (
    select *,
        case when extended_date <
                  lead(s_date, 1, cast('99991231' as date)) over (
                      partition by dr order by s_date, extended_date) then 1 end as brk
    from nonsubsumed_ranges
), groups as (
    select *, sum(brk) over (
                  partition by dr order by s_date desc, extended_date desc) as grp
    from breaks
)
select patid, Generic_Name, Route, Route_value,
    min(s_date), max(e_date), max(cadance_value) /*?*/
from groups
group by dr, patid, Generic_Name, Route, Route_value, grp
order by dr, patid, Generic_Name, Route, Route_value, grp;

https://dbfiddle.uk/juTiXRu6

@shawnt00.Your code returned 5 records for patid =135 but it was supposed to be 4 records

patid=106 is supposed to be 3 records

@Drdre01 As you can see I'm only using the oldest version of the sample data which doesn't even have a patient 106. I think I've given you enough help. You can step up and take over from here until you have specific feedback that goes beyond "It doesn't work."

This query provides the expected results. I suspect you can provide more examples to help us fine tune this solution.
SELECT [patid],[Generic_Name], Route, Route_value, min(s_date) as s_date, max(e_date) as e_date, max(cadance_value) as cadance_value
FROM #prescribed_data
GROUP BY [patid],[Generic_Name],Route, Route_value

fiddle



patid
Generic_Name
Route
Route_value
s_date
e_date
cadance_value




135
Haloperidol Decanoate
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
14


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
O
IM
2017-03-29
2017-03-29
null


135
Paliperidone Palmitate
R
IM
2017-02-16
2018-07-27
30


135
risperiDONE Consta
R
IM
2017-04-05
2017-07-05
null




#Bart McEndree. I added more examples and details
